# This code keeps looping when the variable "op" is not in the "valid" list

Tags: python

```
    valid = (None, "add", "sub", "mul", "div")
    num = 0

    operation = "add"

    print("Operations: add(addition), sub(subtraction), mul(multiplication), div(division), adv(advanced)")

    op = None

    while True:

     print(num)

     op = str(input("Math operation: "))

     while True:

    print(num)

    if op not in valid:

  print("invalid operation!")

  op = None

  continue

if op == "add":

  operation = "add"

  num_ = float(input("Add: "))

  if num_ != 0:

    num += num_

    continue

  else:

    break

    continue

elif op == "sub":

  operation = "sub"

  num_ = float(input("Subtract: "))

  if num_ != 0:

    num -= num_

    continue

  else:

    break

    continue

elif op == "mul":

  operation = "mul"

  num_ = float(input("Multiply: "))

  if num_ != 0:

    num *= num_

    continue

  else:

    break

    continue

elif op == "div":

  operation = "div"

  num_ = float(input("Divide: "))

  if num_ != 0:

    num /= num_

    continue

  else:

    break
```

Comment: Please update the question code to fix the formatting and indentation.

Comment: It's not just that your code is hard to read.  Since indentation is part of the syntax in Python, there's no way we can tell you what's wrong with your code.  The code won't compile in its current form.  It could very well be that something is indented incorrectly in your code.  There's way to tell with the code in its current form.  So when you clean up the code, be careful to make sure that the indentation is the same as your actual code.  BTW, please remove all of the extra blank lines.  You may want a few blank lines to organize the code a bit, but just a few please.

Comment: I think I know what your problem is, but I can't be sure until you fix your formatting.

Comment: @CryptoFool I think I figured out the right indentation maybe.

Comment: @CryptoFool could you update the indentation to the one I made, so that more people can figure out an answer.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct indentation(I think)

```
valid = (None, "add", "sub", "mul", "div")
num = 0
  

  
operation = "add"

print("Operations: add(addition), sub(subtraction), mul(multiplication), div(division), adv(advanced)")

op = None

while True:

    print(num)

    op = str(input("Math operation: "))

    while True:

        print(num)

        if op not in valid:

            print("invalid operation!")

            op = None

            continue

        if op == "add":

            operation = "add"

            num_ = float(input("Add: "))

            if num_ != 0:

                num += num_

                continue

            else:

                break

                continue

        elif op == "sub":

            operation = "sub"

            num_ = float(input("Subtract: "))

            if num_ != 0:

                num -= num_

                continue

            else:

                break

                continue

        elif op == "mul":

            operation = "mul"

            num_ = float(input("Multiply: "))

            if num_ != 0:

                num *= num_

                continue

            else:

                break

                continue

        elif op == "div":

            operation = "div"

            num_ = float(input("Divide: "))

            if num_ != 0:

                num /= num_

                continue

            else:

                break
```

This seems to also reproduce the error when you input an operation not listed `valid`.
The fix for this would be to break from the code and instead of putting in `continue` you would change it with `break`.

The fix:

```
valid = (None, "add", "sub", "mul", "div")
num = 0

operation = "add"

print("Operations: add(addition), sub(subtraction), mul(multiplication), div(division), adv(advanced)")

op = None

while True:

    print(num)

    op = str(input("Math operation: "))

    while True:

        print(num)

        if op not in valid:

            print("invalid operation!")

            op = None
            #the break
            break
        if op == "add":

            operation = "add"

            num_ = float(input("Add: "))

            if num_ != 0:

                num += num_

                continue

            else:

                break

                continue

        elif op == "sub":

            operation = "sub"

            num_ = float(input("Subtract: "))

            if num_ != 0:

                num -= num_

                continue

            else:

                break

                continue

        elif op == "mul":

            operation = "mul"

            num_ = float(input("Multiply: "))

            if num_ != 0:

                num *= num_

                continue

            else:

                break

                continue

        elif op == "div":

            operation = "div"

            num_ = float(input("Divide: "))

            if num_ != 0:

                num /= num_

                continue

            else:

                break
```

The output:

```
Operations: add(addition), sub(subtraction), mul(multiplication), div(division), adv(advanced)
0
Math operation: no
0
invalid operation!
0
Math operation: no
0
invalid operation!
0
Math operation:
```